# RubyGem twitter direct message text

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

I start the Ruby and I want to do a bot who take the text of direct message received and tweet it. I use the twitter gem and I have no idea how to do it. Can someone help me ?
Tanks a lot
Aurélien

Answer (score 0):

Good News!  The twitter API allows for [reading private messages](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages/show).

The gem provides documentation on recieving a list of messages [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/DirectMessages#direct_messages_received-instance_method).

Your call would look something like this:

```
direct_messages_received(options = {:count => 10})
```

This will return the 10 most recent DMs received.

Comment: Yeah Thanks you. But I already see this command and I now for tweet  it's update. My main problem is to make this commands work together :/ @thisischuck

Comment: You may be able to call direct_messages_reccieved inside of the call to post new tweet function call.